# Visual Studio Xamarin automatic provisioning not working

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I used Visual Studio 2019 to create a new xamarin.ios project.
Went to project's properties and selected Automatic Provisioning.
Went to tools Options Xamarin > Apple Accounts > did Add and entered my Apple ID and password, and it hangs.

I've tried restarting everything and started from a new Xamarin.ios project.

The Apple Development account I just purchased today.

[image]

Comment: I am having the same issue.  It just started happening.  I can log into iTunes connect and I have no new agreements to accept.  On VS for the MAC when I attempt to add my Apple ID, I get a Connection Timed Out error.  On Windows it just seems to site there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you start the automatic signing process, you should ensure that you have an Apple ID added in Visual Studio, as described in the [Apple Account Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/apple-account-management?tabs=windows) guide. Once you've added an Apple ID, you can use any associated Team. This allows certificates, profiles, and other IDs to be made against the team. The team ID is also used to create a prefix for an App ID that will be included in the provisioning profile. Having this allows Apple to verify that you are who you say you are.

To automatically sign your app for deployment on an iOS device, do the following:

1. **Pair Visual Studio 2019 to a Mac** as described in the Pair to Mac guide.
2. In the **Solution** Explorer, right-click the project name and select **Properties**. Then, navigate to the iOS Bundle Signing tab.
3. Select the **Automatic Provisioning** scheme:
   [image]
4. Select your team from the **Team** combo box to start the automatic signing process.
   [image]
5. This starts the automatic signing process. Visual Studio then attempts to generate an App ID, provisioning profile, and a signing identity to use these artifacts for signing. You can see the generation process in the Build output:

Here is [the official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?tabs=windows) with training video by James.